# Working with submodules within submodules

Tags: git, github, nested, git-submodules, git-clone

I am experiencing some troubles managing some repositories on Github.
I am actiually mainting a pathfinding library. The master repo is here: [Jumper](https://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper).This repo connected to 2 others, included as submodules ([30log](https://github.com/Yonaba/30log) and [Binary-Heaps](https://github.com/Yonaba/Binary-Heaps)).

When I attempt to clone the master repo (Jumper), using *--recursive* as an option, **it works fine.**

But, when I want to include this master repo as a submodule in another one, let's call it **SuperMaster repo**, and then I attempt to *clone SuperMaster repo*, still using *--recursive*, it succeeds to clone the repo *Jumper*, but fails to register its submodules (*30log* and *Binary-Heaps*), saying something like:

```
Failed to recurse into submodule path 
fatal: not a git repository: ../../../../c:/Users/... etc
```

I dug a bit, and I found some people have encountered something similar ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327628/why-does-recursive-submodule-update-from-github-fail-for-doctrinemongoormmodule) and [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-submodule-path-computation-bug-with-recursive-submodules-td7562568.html)) but noone of the solutions proposed seems to work with me.

Comment: It sounds as if the URLs in `.gitmodules` either in `Jumper` or the `SuperMaster` repository are wrong - could you edit your question to include the contents of those files?  What commands did you use to add the submodules?  What version of git are you using (`git --version`) and which Windows variant are you using (e.g. is this mSysGit or Cygwin)?

Comment: Hi. I am using msisGit.1 (v1.7.10), running under Windows 7 (x86). To register Jumper's submodules, I used `git submodule add git://github.com/Yonaba/30log core/third-party/30log`, then `git submodule add git://github.com/Yonaba/Binary-Heaps core/third-party/Binary-Heaps`. That worked fine. Now in the SuperMaster repo, I included Jumper as a submodule using `git submodule add git://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper lib/Jumper`. This one worked fine too, then I tried to init the submodule Jumper using `cd lib/Jumper`, then `git submodule update --init --recursive`. That's were it failed.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to `cd` into `lib/Jumper`. Call `git submodule update --init --recursive` from the root of the top level repo. Submodule commands can only be executed from root of dir of a repo. Also, if you are using local urls, submodules have problems with relative paths. The error that you are getting may imply that you are using a local file path instead of a url. But most likely it's that you are not calling the submodule command from what is a root level in a repo.